# Tor and circuits

Tags: circuit

I'm running Tor and need to know an IP address of my latest node.

There is my config:

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it

AvoidDiskWrites 1
LearnCircuitBuildTimeout 0
CircuitBuildTimeout 60
CircuitIdleTimeout 1800
CircuitStreamTimeout 60
ClientOnly 1
ControlListenAddress 127.0.0.1
ControlPort 11000
DataDirectory [cropped]
DirReqStatistics 0
ExcludeNodes {??}
ExcludeExitNodes {??}
ExtraInfoStatistics 0
FastFirstHopPK 0
GeoIPExcludeUnknown 1
GeoIPFile [cropped]/geoip
GeoIPv6File [cropped]/geoip6
HashedControlPassword 16:[cropped]
KeepalivePeriod 600
Log notice stdout
MaxCircuitDirtiness 86400
MaxClientCircuitsPending 60
NewCircuitPeriod 60
WarnUnsafeSocks 0
NumCPUs 1
NumEntryGuards 8
PidFile [cropped]/pid
SafeSocks 1
SocksListenAddress 127.0.0.1
SocksPort 10000
SocksTimeout 60
Support022HiddenServices 0
UseNTorHandshake 0
```

After a couple of seconds I establish connection to Tor control port. Then, after I have an established connection, I request via telnet `getinfo circuit-status` command what prints to me all builded circuits. There is an sample output:

```
getinfo circuit-status
250+circuit-status=
14 BUILT $C309A31AD772FFDD0805C9FECB6D4748A7CBF684=ReflexZincOleate,$C11650E31F83E149C855D574B3171CC9CF9BEE19~ididedittheconfig,$4F7914F3E00DCCC0C2230AF56FF03B6C85B4F7E1=zzegu7eePh0chej BUILD_FLAGS=IS_INTERNAL,NEED_CAPACITY,NEED_UPTIME PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-07-11T08:22:15.144333
13 BUILT $D22734C23156AC27E73E3A105E66061A5B4A17A6=Minus,$BA9B13893B8F9284466AF5A1D61526AC176F0035~uNSAubererHodeNSAck,$80A23969F2EFB552EC536D1CE0F1669B2B3E6414=han1 BUILD_FLAGS=IS_INTERNAL,NEED_CAPACITY,NEED_UPTIME PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-07-11T08:22:14.144141
12 BUILT $D22734C23156AC27E73E3A105E66061A5B4A17A6=Minus,$A265F1DBE342A5BC6721C73F7832DAAEC8AC2053~toxiroxiPL,$D1271A1E15C568DA709D3A1E68188EEAE8DDB834=worfedpm BUILD_FLAGS=NEED_CAPACITY PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-07-11T08:22:13.144935
11 BUILT $D22734C23156AC27E73E3A105E66061A5B4A17A6=Minus,$B7CDFC4D1FF2C53903DDF9D3605F299AE9CB892A=TorUaServAnon,$7E5F5B17CAA9BEF929F57D97EEFE305A2089E901=GEO BUILD_FLAGS=NEED_CAPACITY PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-07-11T08:22:12.147800
.
```

After that I set up connection to Tor socks port and request site which tells me an IP address of my latest node. In this example I get an `31.172.30.1`. Then I again request a `getinfo circuit-status` command, and there is an output:

```
getinfo circuit-status
250+circuit-status=
16 BUILT $3A6A156A01891A13DFAB19A16D2DBABB84F1869B~Unnamed,$63C6AB74A5C288C2159DDC783BB00F88AB44427C=TangeNLV,$48B1B47BD189B86EFD67D93AB6904DAEFFE81B82~chaoscomputerclub18 BUILD_FLAGS=NEED_CAPACITY PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-07-11T08:44:37.144086
15 BUILT $D661820AD807B5D82714462D946FE81526CD4856~toxiroxiLV,$9BF04559224F0F1C3C953D641F1744AF0192543A=geekbox,$44B9D9C24E3C04054AE0A47080CC55461A1AC116=CoinTossTail BUILD_FLAGS=NEED_CAPACITY PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-07-11T08:43:37.144304
14 BUILT $C309A31AD772FFDD0805C9FECB6D4748A7CBF684=ReflexZincOleate,$C11650E31F83E149C855D574B3171CC9CF9BEE19~ididedittheconfig,$4F7914F3E00DCCC0C2230AF56FF03B6C85B4F7E1=zzegu7eePh0chej BUILD_FLAGS=IS_INTERNAL,NEED_CAPACITY,NEED_UPTIME PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-07-11T08:22:15.144333
13 BUILT $D22734C23156AC27E73E3A105E66061A5B4A17A6=Minus,$BA9B13893B8F9284466AF5A1D61526AC176F0035~uNSAubererHodeNSAck,$80A23969F2EFB552EC536D1CE0F1669B2B3E6414=han1 BUILD_FLAGS=IS_INTERNAL,NEED_CAPACITY,NEED_UPTIME PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-07-11T08:22:14.144141
12 BUILT $D22734C23156AC27E73E3A105E66061A5B4A17A6=Minus,$A265F1DBE342A5BC6721C73F7832DAAEC8AC2053~toxiroxiPL,$D1271A1E15C568DA709D3A1E68188EEAE8DDB834=worfedpm BUILD_FLAGS=NEED_CAPACITY PURPOSE=PATH_BIAS_TESTING TIME_CREATED=2014-07-11T08:22:13.144935
11 BUILT $D22734C23156AC27E73E3A105E66061A5B4A17A6=Minus,$B7CDFC4D1FF2C53903DDF9D3605F299AE9CB892A=TorUaServAnon,$7E5F5B17CAA9BEF929F57D97EEFE305A2089E901=GEO BUILD_FLAGS=NEED_CAPACITY PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-07-11T08:22:12.147800
.
```

Now there is more circuits. Why? Then I go to TorStatus site and search for fingerprint of `31.172.30.1` node. Now I know that it is a latest node at circuit number `16` with fingerprint `48B1B47BD189B86EFD67D93AB6904DAEFFE81B82` and `chaoscomputerclub18` router name. It is a final conclusion. So, the questions are:

1. Is it right conclusion?
2. Why Tor created a more circuits and not uses circuit at number `14`?
3. How I can get Tor bootstrap status via telnet, without a reading notice log file?

Comment: Your tor client knows also the ip addresses of each node: GETINFO ns/name/48B1B47BD189B86EFD67D93AB6904DAEFFE81B82