# Where do you get 'getinfo' and 'circuit-status' from?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, debian

I looked at hiprivet's question [Tor and circuits](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/tor-and-circuits). I am running Debian mixed environment (testing, sid/unstable and experimental) and at least in the debian database there aren't any binaries named getinfo and circuit-status. Are there some binaries that need to be compiled or what ?

Looking forward to know more.

Answer (score 2):

If your Tor listens to a **Control Port** you can connect to it (using telnet or netcat or so) and enter commands to control / configure / interrogate it. [Arm](https://www.torproject.org/projects/arm.html.en) also has a CLI for this (on page 5).

See [the Tor manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ControlPort) on listening and connecting to a control port.

See [Tor Control protocol spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git?a=blob_plain;hb=HEAD;f=control-spec.txt) on what you can do/ask through this interface.